# Using VBA my code does not execute the first time and condition is "true"

Tags: excel, vba

Copying 2 columns of data from second spreadsheet (GL Interfaces) when IDs on the 2 sheets match.  I stepped through the code and the code is executed that captures the values and print to the destination, except nothing prints in the G2 a& H2. There is values that should print but does not.  Every other line is printed.

Why does the first execution do not print the values?  Actually, the values did appear once after the second execution.

But when I reset the destination columns to blank and tried again the values from the first evaluation of true will not show up in their destination columns.

Why?

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Dim lastRw1, lastRw2, nxtRw, m, lastColumn, rowCol

    'Determine last row with data, Sheet1
    lastRw1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Determine last row with data, Import
      lastRw2 = Sheets("GL Interfaces").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Last Column
     With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
     End With
     MsgBox lastColumn '=> returns 36

    'Heading
     Range("A1:H1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     Range("A1:H1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     Range("A1:H1").Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)
     Range("A1:H7172").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    'Body
     Range("A1:H7172").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     Range("A1:H7172").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    'Loop through Sheet1, Column A
     For nxtRw = 2 To lastRw2
    'Search Sheet1 Column A for value from GL Interfaces
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRw1)
            Set m = .Find(Sheets("GL Interfaces").Range("A" & nxtRw), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            'Copy GL Interfaces row if match is found
            If Not m Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("GL Interfaces").Range("E" & nxtRw & ":F" & nxtRw).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & m.Row)
            End If
        End With
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you do this with a vlookup?

Comment: Unqualified `Range` calls are implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. Pull `Sheets("GL Interfaces")` and `Sheets("Sheet1")` into their own `Worksheet` object variables, and use them to properly and explicitly qualify these `Range` member calls; it's not clear what sheet you mean to be working with.